# Representing a number in 12 Bit 2's Complement Fixed Point

Tags: binary

The original question is as follows:

> Consider a 12-bit two's complement fixed point representation, with 8 bits for the integer part and 4 bits for the fraction.
>   What is the binary encoding of the decimal value 45.625?

I found the binary representation for `4510` in 8 bits to be `001011012`

I then split the `.62510` into a `.510` and a `.12510`

`.510` in binary is `.12`

`.12510` in binary is `.0012`

Therefore, I came up with the final answer of `00101101.10102`

However, this was counted incorrect.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Looks correct to me. Did they not tell you what they thought the correct answer was?

Comment: No, they did not offer a correct answer, unfortunately. If enough people confirm my answer, however, I may approach the instructor and see if the key is incorrect.

Comment: Double-check the problem too. The fact that "two's complement" was specified yet the number is positive (and thus, whether it's in two's complement or not makes no difference) puzzled me a bit.

Comment: That may have been a trick to try to get us to "flip and add 1" as though it was a negative number. But I'll check on that for sure.

Comment: Ideally, you would go to the instructor note that it is marked incorrect, work through the problem with the instructor, to see what the instructor comes up with, and then check the key again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer to your question:

If there is *any* reason why it was counted incorrect, it would be in the notation you used.  I don't know what the expected notation was, but binary numbers typically don't have decimal points, so for me the correct answer would simply be `0010 1101 1010` or `001011011010` or even `0b001011011010`.  I would hope that your professor/teacher would make format requirements clear.

## Verifying the answer you received:

The answer you came up with is definitely correct, but I want to give a different approach for achieving the same result.  Normally when we convert from binary to decimal we think of powers of two.  eg:

```
(Bit #) (Decimal value)
...       ...
4         16
3         8
2         4
1         2
0         1
```

But consider the following 'mapping' between bits and decimal numbers:

```
11   128 (Actually becomes the sign bit in 2s complement)
10   64
9    32
8    16
7    8
6    4
5    2
4    1
.    (just for reference where you're putting the decimal point)
3    0.5
2    0.25
1    0.125 (provided in the example given)
0    0.0625
```

In your problem statement you say .001<sub>2</sub> == .125<sub>10</sub>.  From that, we can actually build the above table. What we're trying to do is come up with a scaling factor between the two tables above.  How do we do that? Look at bits in the same position, and make a ratio between the two.  In the top table, bit 0 equals `1`.  In the bottom table, bit 0 equals `0.0625`.  We choose bit 0 because on one side it's equal to 1 which makes calculations easier.  These don't really have units, but if they did it might be something like:

```
1 standard binary encoding (sbe) = 0.0625 our encoding (oe)
```

Using our resolution, we can essentially do dimensional analysis on the 'units'. Then we can crunch the calculation (units cancel and we're left with 'sbe'):

```
45.625 oe * (1 sbe / 0.0625 oe) = 730 sbe
```

And if you look at the 'standard' binary value of 730, you'll see: `0010 1101 1010` or as you put it in your question: `00101101.1010`.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer.  The professor did not make the format requirements clear as the example in class contained a decimal, but the homework is considered correct _without_ the decimal.  All I had to do was drop it.

Comment: Of course binary numbers don't have decimal points:  They have _binary_ points.